# Jinja: compare items in list in a for loop

Tags: jinja2

I've got a list this list

```
[
{'update': datetime.date(2019, 9, 13), 'initiator': 'john', 'change': 'name', 'old_value': 'smith', 'new_value': 'baker'}, 
{'update': datetime.date(2019, 9, 13), 'initiator': 'john', 'change': 'name', 'old_value': 'baker', 'new_value': 'ford'}, 
{'update': datetime.date(2019, 10, 25), 'initiator': 'paul', 'change': 'country', 'old_value': 'berlin', 'new_value': 'paris'}, 
{'update': datetime.date(2019, 10, 25), 'initiator': 'john', 'change': 'status', 'old_value': 'hired', 'new_value': 'fired'}
]
```

In my template, the list should be displayed in such a way that the date comes first and below all changes to the date.
A new section should be created for a new date:

```
2019-9-13
john | name | smith | baker
john | name | baker | ford

2019-10-25
paul | country | berlin | paris
john | status | hired | fired
```

I already tried to loop the list and count the loop.index to compare the actual update to the next update in the loop

```
{% for line in history %}
    {% if loop.index != loop.length %}
        {% if loop.first %}
            {{ line.update }} <br>| {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% elif history[loop.index].update == history[loop.index + 1].update %}
            | {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% elif history[loop.index].update != history[loop.index + 1].update %}
            {{ line.update }} <br>| {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {% if  history[loop.index].update == history[loop.index - 1].update%}
            | {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% else %}
            {{ line.update }} <br>| {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's not working.
My next idea was to declare a value to safe the recent date and compare it to the next one in the loop.

```
{% for line in history %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        {% set date = line.update %}
        {{ line.update }} <br>| {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
    {% else %}
        {% if date == line.update %}
            | {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% else %}
            {% set date = line.update %}
            {{ line.update }} <br>| {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }} <br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe someone has an advice or a hint for me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sometime you just need some sleep :-)
This does exactly what I want:

```
{% set date = history[0].update %}
{% for line in history %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        {{ line.update }}<br>
        {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }}
    {% else %}
        {% if date == line.update %}
            <br> {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }}
        {% else %}
            {% set date = line.update %}
            <br><br>{{ line.update }}<br>
            {{ line.initiator }} | {{ line.change }} | {{ line.old_value }} | {{ line.new_value }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```